# Is CSS layout really as delicate as it seems to be?

Tags: css, layout

I have been experimenting with the [Majestic template](http://www.freecsstemplates.org/preview/majestic) at freecsstemplates.org.  So far so good; I really like the look (or to be more specific, my boss really likes the look).

However, I am noticing that the CSS that drives this template seems very brittle; small changes can cause really radical breakage.  In particular, if I reduce the size of the header in the CSS (to eliminate some of the empty space at the top of the page), both of the outside columns suddenly disappear.

With small websites, sometimes I cry uncle and just use tables for layout.  I realize this is heretical; should I be leaving the design to the professional designers?  Or maybe I'm going about this the wrong way, and someone can set me straight.

Comment: yeah....it's just a shitty template. either leave the CSS to the pros, or play with it.... a lot. CSS kind of kicks you in the nuts til you get a feel for it, then you figure out how to manipulate it how you want without too much pain....

Comment: The template is OK, it just had a misplaced /div tag. See my comment in the accepted answer below.

Comment: It might have been my fault, or the fault of the open-source editor I was using.  I went back and looked at the original template from the zip file I downloaded, and it looks fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I honestly think this layout has been made pretty badly. The width of the elements seems to change where they appear on the page, and they're all need to be pixel perfect for everything to be centred.

For some bizarre reason the whole page has been placed inside the div element marked 'header'... This doesn't make much semantic sense for a start.

However, it seems if you decrease the width of every element which has one, then everything does get smaller, and nothing should disappear.

I would recommend looking at some other more sensible layouts, since I don't think this is a very good way of attaining that style -- as you've said, it's brittle. Have you tried using the extension [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for firefox? It allows you to make on-the-fly changes to the css, and see how it affects the style, which will help you learn fast.

Comment: I took the template, ran it through a pretty printer, and looked at the div's. Sure enough, the /div tag for the header was at the bottom of the page. There is already a "wrapper" div for the main body of the page, so I decided to move the /div tag for the header to where it looked like it was supposed to go, and now the template is responding properly to simple sizing tweaks. You get the green checkmark!

Answer (score 4):

CSS is delicate, but still easier to deal with than a site full of table layouts.  I found Dave Shea's book CSS ZenGarden to be a great help in learning CSS from a designers perspective.

Often in layered templates there are a few places where changes to CSS can be made, and it can be really confusing to follow which selectors are controlling the element you wish to manage.  There are many tools out there that can help, but some that have been useful to me are:

- Google Chrome and its Inspect Element option
- [Selector Gadget](http://www.selectorgadget.com/) - a bookmarklet that will help you visually determine the selectors that affect an element
- Firefox's Web Developer plug in

One other tip is to learn about the !important modifier - it can come in handy to force a particular property setting when there are multiple CSS selectors affecting the same element.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give those tools a try.

Answer (score 3):

CSS in my experience is easy to understand in concept, but takes a long time to master.
Brittle CSS can be very brittle, but good CSS can be wonderfully flexible.

Comment: Is the template my boss picked a decent one, or am I going down a dark alley?

Comment: Just glancing at it for a second it seems a bit "forced", e.g. both `#header` and `#logo` are fixed to the same pixel width, even though one is nested inside the other. So I'm not surprised you're experiencing weird side effects.

Answer (score 2):

As it stands CSS can either make layouts wonderfully simple and flexible or it can make the simplest of tasks an absolute nightmare.

Purists will tell you to use CSS no matter what, a *pragmatist* will tell you to use what works.  If using a table or non-CSS solution makes something infinitely easier to do, then use it!

Personally I try to use pure CSS as much as possible, but there have been times when I want to do nothing but swear when something glorious in FireFox looks awful in IE.  This is where the hacks come in.  It is these hacks and work arounds that tend to make CSS brittle in the first place.

Half the problems with CSS would go away if *all* the browsers did precisely what the CSS spec says they should do.  Alas, this is yet to happen so we have to live with either using tables, or on occassion, brittle CSS.

The best solution is to make the design as simple as possible.  If you find you have a hundred divs and lots of CSS trickery to do something straight-forward, stop.  Re-think how you are approaching it and try again.

At the end of the day your website users don't really give a monkeys what your website looks like as long as they can get at the information they want with minimum effort.  Successfully manage that and they will not care how photorealistic that shiny nav bar is, or how well the borders line up etc.

That's my 18pence at any rate :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree most css template is hard to read, and different people may have a very different approach to the same layout strategy. Since there are too many hacks/tricks/techniques in css it is really fragile when you try to modify those existing one since almost all cases, the styles are very dependent to each other.

Comment: Are there alternatives?  Perhaps a JQuery-like CSS library that abstracts out all the brittleness?

Comment: "JQuery-like CSS library"? If you have recommendation, I am open to see how it works. Currently, there are many CSS frameworks in the market, they are easy to use and ok to understand..... BUT not friendly to markup and it mess up layout with html again, which is no better than using table layout. I still hand coding CSS with only little help from VS intellisense coz still no better generator compare to direct css manipulation.

Comment: I think you can get yourself into more trouble when using a CSS "Framework" as when things go wrong, it's really hard to fix where as if you write the layout yourself you understand it much better.

Yes, there are pitfalls all over the place with CSS. But it is possible to do it in such a way that's reasonably hack-free and not so brittle.

BTW - Use Firebug for Firefox (http://www.getfirebug.com). By FAR the best tool for debugging and tweaking your HTML/CSS.

Comment: @wows, I am not a fan or supporter of any css framework. Just consider it put something like <div class="col-3"> into html is already out of any consideration. I'd rather like to put <table> instead of those nonsense classes.

Answer (score 0):

Css doesn't break as long as you don't break it ;) It's a language. Just like a regular one, if you don't use proper grammar people won't understand what your saying. 
If a layout doesn't work or suddenly your page looks rubbish, I'll guarantee you it's your fault. Css isn't brittle, the code you wrote with it might be.

So start by learning the basics and don't just dive into some file you found online which might (in your case, does) contain very bad code.

If you end up wanting to use tables for everything may I suggest you start looking at some grid systems like http://960.gs/ and ease your pain.

Gideon